# Por and Para origins

Tags: definiciones, etimología

How did **por** and **para** come to mean so differently in Spanish while they both come from the same source, i.e., Latin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been researching a bit because I found the question really interesting:

### POR

The preposition **por** comes from the latin *pro* (meaning forward, move forward; like ***pro**babilidad*, ***pro**genitor* or ***pro**greso*) with the influence of *per-* (meaning through, complete; like ***per**plejo*). Both come from the same indoeuropean root *per* from where a lot of greek prefixes come from (*para-*, *peri-*, *pro-*, *proto-*).

### PARA

Some say that the preposition **para**, previously used as *pora*, comes from latin *pro ad* (forward to), but others say that it comes from *per ad* (for).

I see that the sources are not exactly the same. We can say that one is related to the other, but it is not the same word. This difference between **por** and **para** happens also in Portuguese (they use the same words **por** and **para**), I'm not sure but also in French I think (**par**, and **pour** [some French-speaker check this please]), but it's not like that in Italian (**per**). I guess they lost that distinction somewhere, however other languages did not.

Comment: And you can go even crazier with Asturian — which added an extra one and distinguishes *por*, *per*, and *pa*.

Comment: Yes, French has *par* and *pour*. However, the distinction between these two does not map to the distinction between *por* and *para* in Spanish. *Par* is used in French in a smaller number of cases than *para* is used in Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

Según el [RAE](http://www.rae.es/):

> [para](http://dle.rae.es/para) proviene del antiguo `pora`
>
> [por](http://dle.rae.es/por) del latin `pro` influenciado por `per`.

Como puedes apreciar sus orígenes son distintos, aunque `para` en una de sus definiciones puede usarse en lugar de `por`

> **Para**: 8. prep. Por, o a fin de. Para acabar la pendencia, me llevé a uno de los que reñían.